# How to enable Wpbakery Page Builder(Visual Composer) in CMB2 "wysiwyg" type?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, wpbakery

I am adding a custom metabox text editor in wordpress with CMB2 for post type. Here Wpbakery Page Builder(Visual Composer) is enabled in default post type editor. but i can't able to  enable Wpbakery Page Builder(Visual Composer) in custom post editor which i have implemented with CMB2 metabox. It has been implemented with "wysiwyg" type. Is there any way to enable Wpbakery Page Builder(Visual Composer) in CMB2 "wysiwyg" type? Thanks for help...

Answer (score 0):

WPBakery Page Builder(Visual Composer) can not be implemented in CMB2 "wysiwyg" type editor. VC does not support this feature. **It can only be used for main WP content area.**